# Failed to import 3 rows: ParseError - Invalid row length 1 should be 3, given up without retries

Tags: csv, cassandra, cqlsh

I am trying to import csv file with delimiter=’|’. I am getting this repeated error, I am struggling like this for two days. Any help will be appreciated. Below are details.

```
Cassandra Version:
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.9 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]
```

This is my csv:

```
row_nr|PRD_ID|X_01

1|3170428144631014|25603.24
2|3170428144632015|25606.24
4|3170428144633017|25602.24
```

Created Keyspace:

```
create keyspace newpqp with replication = {'class:''simplestrategy', 'replication_factor':1};
```

Create Table:

```
CREATE TABLE againcheckdel(row_nr int primary key,PRD_ID bigint, X_01 decimal);
```

Copy command:

```
COPY againcheckdel(row_nr,PRD_ID,X_01) FROM 'C:\Users\skum\Documents\mytrial.csv' WITH  HEADER = 'true' AND DELIMITER = '|';
```

Error:

```
cqlsh:samplepqp> COPY againcheckdel(row_nr,PRD_ID,X_01) FROM 'C:\Users\skum\Documents\mytrial.csv' WITH  HEADER = 'true' AND DELIMITER = '|';

Using 7 child processes

Starting copy of samplepqp.againcheckdel with columns [row_nr, prd_id, x_01].
Failed to import 3 rows: ParseError - Invalid row length 1 should be 3,  given up without retries
Failed to process 3 rows; failed rows written to import_samplepqp_againcheckdel.err
Processed: 3 rows; Rate:       2 rows/s; Avg. rate:       3 rows/s
3 rows imported from 1 files in 1.091 seconds (0 skipped).
```

What am I doing wrong? Please correct me.

Comment: The error say that your csv file is not in correct format. But your csv file seems ok. Are you importing the right file ?

Comment: Yes, I am importing correct file. Can you suggest me a csv in correct format?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam i got the data. Pls see my answer and thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally data is imported.

Make sure that order of columns in csv is same as in table. To do it follow below syntax for creating table.

```
CREATE TABLE fornormal(Unnamed int,row_nr int, PRD_ID bigint, X_01 decimal, primary key (Unnamed, row_nr, PRD_ID, X_01));
cqlsh:samplepqp> select * from fornormal;

 unnamed | row_nr | prd_id | x_01
---------+--------+--------+------
```

Below is copy command.

```
COPY fornormal FROM 'C:\Users\skum\Documents\normalcsv.csv' WITH HEADER = TRUE AND DELIMITER = '|';
Using 7 child processes

Starting copy of samplepqp.fornormal with columns [unnamed, row_nr, prd_id, x_01].
Processed: 941 rows; Rate:     471 rows/s; Avg. rate:     848 rows/s
941 rows imported from 1 files in 1.111 seconds (0 skipped).
cqlsh:samplepqp> select * from fornormal;

 unnamed | row_nr | prd_id           | x_01
---------+--------+------------------+---------
     769 |    770 | 3170428150618780 | 25606.7
      23 |     24 | 3170428144646030 | 25601.9
     114 |    115 | 3170428145810120 | 25600.3
```